# Unity3d UI elements change position

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, resolution

I made a simple app in Unity3d, that generate six random different numbers when a button is pressed.The numbers that are generated are simply six UI Texts that are child to a Canvas. My problem is that those texts change their position, depending on the dimension of the screen:
[Texts position in full screen mode.](http://postimg.org/image/4li4hddkl/)
[Texts position in normal mode](http://postimg.org/image/vls5q3sg3/)

This is the script that i've used:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    float rx = Screen.width / 1080.0f;
    float ry = Screen.height / 1920.0f;
    GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0,0,0),Quaternion.identity,new Vector3(rx,ry,1));

    GUI.skin = GameSkin;

    if (GUI.Button (GenerateRect, "GENERATE"))
                    GenerateNumbers ();
}

private void GenerateNumbers()
{
    int n;
        for(int i = 1;i<=6;i++)
        {
            n = UnityEngine.Random.Range (1, 100);
            while(nr.Contains(n))  /this while loop ensure that the numbers are different
                n = UnityEngine.Random.Range (1, 100);
            nr.Add (n);  // here nr is a list<int> that contains the numbers.
        }

        Nr1.text = nr[0].ToString();
        Nr2.text = nr[1].ToString();
        Nr3.text = nr[2].ToString();
        Nr4.text = nr[3].ToString();
        Nr5.text = nr[4].ToString();
        Nr6.text = nr[5].ToString();
        nr.Clear();

    }
    StartCoroutine ("ShowNumbers"); //the ShowNumbers coroutine show the numbers.
}
```

I am using Unity 4.6(beta)
P.S. Sorry for bad english, I'm from Romania.

Comment: I think that, you need to set the positions of all Nrs from a script based on the screen size.

Comment: And how could i set the position? Is there a in-built propriety that will allow me to adjust the text's position?

Comment: I think they should have transform, if they are gameObjects in your scene. In that case `transform.postion = new Vector3(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);`. Or you can create the text completely from script with [GUI.Box](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Box.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to your code, but your Canvas settings. Select your UI Canvas that is parent to these UI objects and there you will have automatically added script called "Canvas Scaler", there you can setup how do you want your UI to react to resolution change, try to experiment with factors and scaling modes until you get results you are satisfied with.